# How to serve Angular application from .NET 5 server and use Server Side Rendering (SSR) or Pre-rendering?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, pre-rendering

I've spent considerable amount of time on google trying to find some documentation on how to accomplish just that: Server Angular project from .NET 5 server and use Server Side Rendering or Pre-rendering.

I have set up my Angular application for SSR and Pre-rendering and I can accomplish all of that locally by running `dev:ssr` and `serve`. My question is specific to the backend and how to serve the app.

Currently, I am using .NET to serve up the SPA without any special handling like this:

```
.AddSpaStaticFiles(spa => 
 {
    spa.RootPath = "wwwroot";
 });
```

and then:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
```

Does anyone have any documentation on how do service side rendering or pre-rendering?

Comment: Can you use .NET 6? [I forked the code here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing) but it only targets .NET 6. [Here's the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering)

Comment: I've seen this repo and I have also saw your medium blog 
| https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976 | which was beneficial, but I did not want to add a dependency to MintPlayer if I didnt have to. Dependency are a pain especially if the authors in 2 years time do not keep up with framework updates. I'd rather do it without these dependencies. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure. Indeed I don't have an ocean of spare time. It's a pity that SSR was removed from .NET 5 and onwards. What you can do is include the classes from the microsoft 3.1 ssr repo in your own project, but you will find that regularily the build will fail and you'll need to clean+rebuild once in a while...

Comment: Where can I find information that SSR was removed from .NET 5? This whole time re-searching I couldn't find anything about SSR removal. Do you have any insight where that might be?
Are the alternatives simply to NOT use .NET for SSR rather, use something else for that?

Comment: [Obsoleting Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices and Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12890). Microsoft wants to focus their efforts on Blazor development, which supports SSR since all frontend assemblies are .NET, and CSR through the WebAssembly runtime. However, blazor does not play as elegantly with queryparameters as angular does, which is why I kept working with angular...

Comment: I see. I have found a thread on github following that issue you posted, and a guy from MS team said this "As we've had announced earlier, we will be relying on SPA frameworks to provide server side rendering functionality." https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27887#issuecomment-912106128. Which kind of sounds like you should be able to achieve SSR somehow. I just am not sure how yet. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think they mean you should still be able to use `npm run start:ssr`, but you still won't be able to supply data to the SPA, which is a major limitation.

Comment: Thats unfortunate... since my backend is all built on .NET, and I kind of need SSR for SEO, i suppose a way around this would be to use another backend framework, and make a request to the server for any data that is required to be there on page load. I don't have much experience with SSR, but what exactly do you mean by "still won't be able to supply data to the SPA". What type of data one might need but won't have access to?

Comment: If NodeJS on the server doesn't allow you to send http requests to the same server during SSR, you WILL need to pass data, that's normally being retrieved through a http request, through the [`SupplyData`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingExtensions.cs#L175) hook. That is, for whatever variable data you're displaying on your page